# The server encountered an internal error while attempting to Authenticate via Quality Center Rest API

Tags: api, rest, hp-quality-center

After attempting  OurQualityCenter:8080/qcbin/rest/is-authenticated, I get the expected 401.

The next step is to do OurQualityCenter:8080/qcbin/rest/authentication-point/authenticate=Y.

This second browser attempt returns an http error 500. I noticed login_jsp.class seems to be missing.  Can anybody give me some clues as to what is going on here? I am using Quality center 11.

```
`type Exception report
message 
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:593)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.hp.qc.web.restapi.RESTApiFilter.doFilter(RESTApiFilter.java:65)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    com.mercury.optane.core.state.ServerStatusFilter.doFilter(ServerStatusFilter.java:33)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
root cause 
**java.io.FileNotFoundException: no such file: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\HP\ALM\jboss\server\default\work\jboss.web\localhost\qcbin\org\apache\jsp\authentication_002dpoint\login_jsp.class**
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.<init>(SmapUtil.java:253)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:241)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:165)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:454)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:300)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.hp.qc.web.restapi.RESTApiFilter.doFilter(RESTApiFilter.java:65)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    com.mercury.optane.core.state.ServerStatusFilter.doFilter(ServerStatusFilter.java:33)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
`
```

Comment: Do you have any more details about the request you are sending? Like cookies and headers etc.

Comment: @Xiaofu No headers or anything just entered http://OurQualityCenter:8080/qcbin/rest/is-authenticated in the browser as the first step in the authentication process

Answer (score 0):

What it's really telling you is there's no such URL as `https://example.com/qcbin/rest/authentication-point/authenticate`

Delete the "rest" bit: `https://example.com/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate`

At this point you need to be passing in credentials, but that would be a different question...